# Unity2D: The name `EventSystems' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity

I am having a problem with errors that "The name `EventSystems` does not exist in the current context". I made sure that I added `using UnityEngine.EventSystems`, so I'm a bit dumbfounded. Anyway, this is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;  // As you can see, its "using" correctly.

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject currentSelectedGameObject;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
            if (!EventSystems.EventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject ()) {
                Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
                mousePosition.z = 10; // distance from the camera
                target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);
                target.z = transform.position.z;
            }
        }

    transform.position = 
            Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, target, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are "`using`" something, your effectively telling your compiler 'I'm already looking in this directory of libraries'.

When you tell it `using EventSystems`, you can no longer use `EventSystems`, because your already using `EventSystems`. If that makes sense.

Write your `if` statement without the initial `EventSystems`.

```
if (!EventSystem.currentSelectedGameObject ()) {
    Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePosition.z = 10; // distance from the camera
    target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mousePosition);
    target.z = transform.position.z;
}
```

Alternatively, get rid of `using EventSystems`. It is a pretty early topic you should be familiar, with as a programmer, [so you may want to read more at Microsoft's C# Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx) to get a better understanding of it.